# ActionController::UnknownFormat with js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

Im new at ruby and I try to add ajax for my controller, but I`m probably missing something

My controller

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  def search
    if params[:stock].present?
      @stock = Stock.new_lookup(params[:stock])
      if @stock
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js {render partial: 'users/result'}
        end
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Please enter a valid symbol to search"
        redirect_to my_portfolio_path
      end

    else
      flash[:alert] = "Please enter a symbol to search"
      redirect_to my_portfolio_path
    end
  end
end
```

My view. When I`m not writing 'turbo:false' nothing happens

```
<div class="search-area">
  <h3>Search Stocks</h3>
  <%= form_tag search_stock_path, data: {turbo: false}, method: :get do %>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-9 no-right-padding">
        <%= text_field_tag :stock, params[:stock], placeholder: "Stock ticker symbol", autofocus: true, class: "form-control form-control-large"%>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 no-left-padding">
        <%= button_tag type: :submit, class: "btn btn-success" do %>
          <%= fa_icon 'search 1.5x' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My terminal:

```
Started GET "/search_stock?stock=MSFT&button=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-01-27 22:44:35 +0200
Processing by StocksController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"stock"=>"MSFT", "button"=>""}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 1701ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms | Allocations: 8322)


  
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  
app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:6:in `search'
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRked.png)

I found articles with a similar error, but there was no answer

In the terminal I see that but dont know what to do

```
Processing by StocksController#search as HTML
```

Comment: Try adding `remote: true` to the form?

Comment: I did the same but nothing changed

Comment: the 406 is telling you that what you are rendering is unprocessable, I think the statement should be `format.js { render 'users/result' }`, partials are for rendering "partial" reusable pieces of code for views, but what you are doing is rendering a small part of the html without any of the valid doctypes required.

Comment: you need Rails UJS for this or you have to submit the form yourself from javascript and set proper headers. you can also just use Turbo and render *turbo_stream* response.